# How to build the Unit Test project along with the 'Visual Studio Build' task in CI build Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, unit-testing, azure-devops, code-coverage

I am trying to run the unit test cases and calculate code coverage whenever CI build is run .
You can view the build definition in the picture below  .
I am getting the error : 'No test sources found matching the given filter ***bin\Release\UTproject.dll'

When I check the logs of task 'Build Solution' I found that there's no trace of unit test cases being built . Though other projects are getting build .
Can anyone please guide me on what change should I make in the repository or the build to make sure that Unit test project gets built along with other projects ?
Perhaps building the unit test project would resolve the above stated issue in running unit tests along the with Ci build  . Let me know if there's anything else that I am missing  .

Thanks in Advance !

[image: build defibition ni azure devops]

[image: error in running unit test cases]

Comment: Do they build locally? Are you building a configuration in which the project containing the tests is excluded?

Comment: Build runs on the separate build server , we have build agents installed there . There's no  exclusion being set as such .

Comment: I think @DanielMann is asking if when you build locally, are you matching the configuration / platform you have configured on the build solution step?  If they build those projects locally, you are saying you confirmed you are passing the same configuration/platform settings to the build solution step?

Comment: Yes it;s building locally . And I have checked in the Uni test project later  .(As its new compared to other existing project) . Is their anything in .csproj that needs to be checkedin to make sure it gets build on build server ?

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I was able to build the Unit Test project  . Now  ,the unit tests are running when pipeline is queued  . Working on exporting the coverage to sonarqube server , that's still pending   ,let me know if you have any valuable i/p on this part .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I check the logs of task 'Build Solution' I found that there's no trace of unit test cases being built .

According to your description, you need to find out the reason why the unit test project are not built.

So, first, we need make sure we have submit the Unit test project in the repo and the `Visual Studio build` task build the **solution** `.sln` file, not only the project `.csproj` files:

[image]

Second, if the Unit test project is built and we still get the same error, then we need to check **filter** in the option **Test files** in the `Visual Studio Test` task.

As the log showing, you set the filter like:

```
**\*bin\release\xxxxUT.dll
```

So, you need make sure you have set the `configuration=release` when you build the solution in `Visual Studio build` task:

[image]

[image]

Or you could change the filter to:

```
**\*UI*.dll
!**\obj\**
```

And the Search folder should be the folder where the test dll generated, the default value is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! I was able to build the Unit Test project  . Now  ,the unit tests are running when pipeline is queued  . Working on exporting the coverage to sonarqube server , that's still pending   ,let me know if you have any valuable i/p on this part .